# Error in Xcode while combining 2 functions

Tags: c++, xcode, if-statement

I need little help with my homework. It's a project according to what i have to combine 2 programs, and user can make selection which program he wants to run; I'm trying to use IF ELSE statement for that. While running these programs separately they work fine. Xcode is giving me a problem while trying to run first program rand function one. Can you guys help me out.?
Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x;

    cout << "Hello Welcome to my Game Menu. Please make selection from following criteria"  <<endl;
    cout << "Please press 1 if you would like to play The Guessing Game"<<endl;
    cout << "Please press 2 if you would like to play The Math Game"<<endl;
    cin >>x;

    if ( x == 1)
    {
        cout << "Welcome to Guessing Game" <<endl;
        //declare the variables
        int num; //variable to store the random
        //number
        int guess; //variable to store the number
        //guessed by the user
        bool isGuessed; //boolean variable to control
        //the loop

        srand(time(NULL)); //Line 1

        num = rand() % 100; //Line 2

        isGuessed = false; //Line 3

        while (!isGuessed) //Line 4
        { //Line 5
            cout << "Enter an integer greater"
            << " than or equal to 0 and "
            << "less than 100: "; //Line 6

            cin >> guess; //Line 7
            cout << endl; //Line 8

            if (guess == num) //Line 9
            { //Line 10
                cout << "You guessed the correct "
                << "number." << endl; //Line 11
                isGuessed = true; //Line 12
            } //Line 13
            else if (guess < num) //Line 14
                cout << "Your guess is lower than the "
                << "number.\n Guess again!"
                << endl; //Line 15
            else //Line 16
                cout << "Your guess is higher than "
                << "the number.\n Guess again!"
                << endl; //Line 17
        } //end while //Line 18
    }

    else if ( x == 2) {
        cout <<"Welcome to Math Game " <<endl;

        double a,b,x,y,z,sum;
        string name;

        cout << "Please enter your name... ";
        cin>> name;
        cout<<endl;
        cout << "    WELCOME TO MATH MIND TRICKS " <<name <<endl;
        cout<< "I will read your mind." <<endl;
        cout<< "We will choose five , five digit numbers together" <<endl;
        cout<< "but i will be able to give you the sum, just after the first one" <<endl;
        cout<<endl;
        cout<< "What is your first five digit number?"<<endl;
        cin>> x;
        cout<<endl;
        cout<< " The sum is going to be " << 199998+x <<endl;
        cout<< "Please enter a second number" <<endl;
        cin>> y;
        cout<<endl;
        a= 99999-y;
        cout<< " OK, im going to choose    " <<a <<endl;
        cout<< " Please enter your last five digit number" <<endl;
        cin>> z;
        b= 99999-z;
        cout<< " OK, im going to choose    " <<b  <<endl;
        cout<<endl;
        sum = a+b+x+y+z;
        cout<< " The sum of our five numbers is " <<sum <<endl;
        cout<<endl;
        cout <<"Impressed? :)" <<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: It is working fine, i have tested it.

Comment: This Error http://i41.tinypic.com/10xdmc5.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The time() returns an `NSUInteger`, and on the 64-bit OS X platform

- NSUInteger is defined as unsigned long, and
- unsigned long is a 64-bit unsigned integer.
- int is a 32-bit integer.

So int is a "smaller" datatype than NSUInteger, therefore the compiler warning.

See also NSUInteger in the "Foundation Data Types Reference":

When building 32-bit applications, NSUInteger is a 32-bit unsigned integer. A 64-bit application treats NSUInteger as a 64-bit unsigned integer.

To fix that compiler warning, you can either declare the local count variable as

```
NSUInteger count;
```

or (if you are sure that your array will never contain more than 2^31-1 elements!), add an explicit cast:

```
srand((int)time(NULL));
```